# Problemas al guardar el nombre de la imagen en la base de datos

Tags: laravel, array, intervention

Tengo un código que recibe desde un formulario un campo llamado `year` que lo obtengo de un campo oculto en el formulario y otro llamado `file` donde subo las imágenes y estas pueden ser varias al mismo tiempo por lo que utilizo `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'` para ello.

y en el controlador tengo el siguiente código que me funciona bien, subiendo las imágenes al servidor mientras no tengo el campo file, cuando lo tengo me da el siguiente error:

```
ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Array to string conversion
```

Entiendo que el problema está en que no se puede convertir de un array a string pero no sé como resolverlo.

Código del controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required',
            'file.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:3048'
    ]);

    if($request->hasfile('file'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('file') as $file)
        {                
            $bd = Photo::create($request->all());
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/image/', $name); 
            $bd->fill(['file' => $name])->save(); // EL PROBLEMA ESTÁ ACÁ.
        }
    }

    return back()->with('success', 'Your images has been upload successfully');
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que el problema es en esa línea que marcas? Parece tener más sentido de que sea en `$bd = Photo::create($request->all());`, pues si en el campo `file` del request tienes un array, `create()` va a intentar insertar ese array en la columna `file` de tu tabla.

Comment: Cuando elimino la última línea `$bd->fill(['file' => $name])->save();` y dejo el resto, me guarda la información del campo `year`, pero no se guarda en el campo `file`. Ambos campos vienen del formulario `$request->all()`

Comment: ¿Tienes ese atributo `'file'` en la propiedad `$fillable` de tu modelo `Photo`?

Comment: Sí,se lo coloqué.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tu realizas:

```
$bd = Photo::create($request->all());
```

Estas almacenando todos los datos del request en la `base de datos`.

Entonces el error que tienes es **porque en el `request` el dato `file` es un array y de seguro en tu base de datos `file` es un string.** Hasta aquí el motivo de tu error.

**Solución:** No utilices `create` si aun editaras algunas propiedades antes de guardar, una alternativa seria instanciar un objeto, editarlo y por ultimo guardarlo.

```
 $bd = new Photo($request->all());//instancia de Photo
 $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();//preparación de datos
 $file->move(public_path().'/image/', $name); 
 $bd->file=$name;//edición de datos 
 /*hasta este punto deberíamos de estar seguros de la integridad de datos */
 $bd->save();//almacenamiento en la base de datos
```

Hasta aquí tu problema y espero se solucione con eso.

**Consejos:**

1.- Nunca almacenes datos solo con `$request->all()`, parece lo mas rápido y sencillo pero podría traerte muchos problemas a futuro.

2.- Si necesitas almacenar más de una imagen, envíalas una a una; No a todas en conjunto.

Comment: Gracias, voy a revisar y lo adpato a mí necesidad, que es guardar cada imagen en un registro junto a su año correspondiente (Para hacer una tabla tipo piivot), gracias por la recomendaciónla tomaré en cuenta. Con respecto a envíarlas todas, es necesario.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó tal como lo necesitaba. Muy bien explicado, ya lo tendré encuenta para el futuro.